# helper utility type to get union from const string array

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have string arrays that I construct with const assertions then use them to create union types.

```js
const keys = ["foo", "bar", "moo"] as const;
type keysUnion = typeof keys[number]; // type keysUnion = "foo" | "bar" | "moo"
```

Is there a way to make a utility type that does the same thing with having to type `typeof` and `[number]` each time? Asking because I use this pattern multiple times so would be nice to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* remove the `typeof` here, since you cannot use a value in a type. You must use the `typeof` that value when using the type of that value in a another type.

---

That said you could have a type like:

```
type ArrayMember<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T[number]
```

And use it like:

```
const keys = ["foo", "bar", "moo"] as const;
type KeysUnion = ArrayMember<typeof keys> // "foo" | "bar" | "moo"

type MyKey = ArrayMember<string[]> // string
```

It's not much shorter, but it does read more nicely than `MyArrType[number]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAshAtgIwnAPAFSggA9gIA7AEwGco4JFKB7cgGxCgFdyBrcpgO7kA2gF0AfFAC8UfMPKcsOUQCgVAYxbVgUHhBC0ZwgEQAzJk2MAaKMcyI412+gvHRURLU3ltAbhWgkLr61ACq5ACWLNKwCMhoSniBEEymwQbiKkA)

Comment: This is a big help, thanks! This raises one more question for me though, if you have time. The union type gets consumed by a generic function type `func<T extends keyof Entity> = (entity: Pick<Entity, T>) => void`. Is there a way to use ArrayMember inside the function type?

Comment: You could use that `ArrayMember` member all over the place, including in a function type. But, your posted example doesn't have any arrays, so I have no idea where you would use it in that. That is probably a separate question.